# How to define virtual IP programmatically?

Tags: java, vb.net, perl, cmd

I need to define Virtual IP programmatically (Perl or VB or CMD or java).
I need it for temporary use, I can't use any actual IP address and I don't care if it will be accessible only from local machine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Yan

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a home-IP from the `127.0.0.0/8` block? These will all refer to your localhost.

You can there run a program to respond to incoming packets and fake conversations.

Use your hostfile to bind fake hostnames to those IP-addresses.

Comment: While `127.0.0.0/8` is reserved for loopback, its not guaranteed to go anywhere. While it works on the two Debian machines I've tried it doesn't on my Mac. If it does work, its clever!

Comment: WOW, great, this is exactly what i need. I was familiar only with 127.0.0.1.
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!